# UITableViewCell Delete Row Causing Index Out of Range

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code :

```
    class SchedulerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
    scheduleCellDelegate
    {
    
        
        var scheduleArray : Array<Array<String>>?
        var scheduler : [String : Array<Array<String>>]?
        var deviceID : String = ""
        let retrievedString = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token")
    
        var day = ""
        var dayNum = 0
      
        @IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
        @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
        @IBOutlet weak var scheduleView: UITableView!
        
        var header : HTTPHeaders? = nil
        var ScheduleURL : Dictionary<String, String>?
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            scheduleView.delegate = self
            scheduleView.dataSource = self
            spinner.isHidden = true
            //scheduleView.allowsSelection = false
            scheduleView.register(UINib(nibName: "schedulerCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "schedulerCell")
            self.getData()
            
        }
        
        func getData(){

                AFFunctions.getAFRequest(ofType: ScheduleResponse.self, url: ScheduleURL!["GET"]!) { responseData, statusCode in
                    print(responseData?.data?.scheduler, statusCode)
                    self.scheduler = responseData?.data?.scheduler
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
                        self.scheduleView.reloadData()
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
           
            var buttonNum : Int?
            
            @IBAction func daySelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
                
                self.buttons.forEach { $0.tintColor = ($0 == sender) ? UIColor.orange : UIColor.systemTeal }
                
                self.dayNum = sender.tag
                switch dayNum {
                case 0 : self.day = "Sunday"
                case 1 : self.day = "Monday"
                case 2 : self.day = "Tuesday"
                case 3 : self.day = "Wednesday"
                case 4 : self.day = "Thursday"
                case 5 : self.day = "Friday"
                case 6 : self.day = "Saturday"
                default : self.day = "Sunday"
           
            }
            showDetail(day : day,dayNum : dayNum)
        }
        
        func showDetail(day : String, dayNum : Int) {

            if let dayArray = scheduler?[day]
            {  
                scheduleArray = dayArray
                self.scheduleView.reloadData()
            } 
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return scheduleArray?.count ?? 0
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("scheduleCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! scheduleCell
            cell.cellDelegate = self
            cell.editBtn.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.deleteSchedule.tag = indexPath.row
            scheduleArray = scheduler![self.day]
/////////////THE BELOW STATEMENT THROWS THE ERROR ///////////////////
                if let firstLabel = self.scheduleArray?[indexPath.row][0], let secondLabel = self.scheduleArray?[indexPath.row][1] {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.timeLabel1.text = firstLabel
                        cell.timeLabel2.text = secondLabel
                    }
                }
            return cell
        }
        
        func didPressButton(_ tag: Int, btnType: String) {
            let deleteURL = K.delURL
            if(btnType == "delete") {
                AFFunctions.deleteAFRequest(ofType: scheduleResponse.self, url: "\(deleteURL)?day=\(self.day)&place=\(tag)") { [self]
                    responseData, statusCode in
                    if(statusCode == 200){
                        let deleteAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Deleted", message: "Device Schedule Successfully Deleted", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    
                        deleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                            
                            self.scheduler![self.day]?.remove(at: tag)
                            self.scheduleView.reloadData()
        
                         }))
                        self.present(deleteAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     
    }
```

I am doing the changes in the array locally as data is fetched only once in ViewDidLoad() with getData function. It shows a schedule for each day of the week (7 buttons, one for each day, are linked to an Outlet Collection), with 2 buttons embedded in the custom cell nib - an edit button and a delete button. I have implemented the logic for deleting, button tags are equal to IndexPath.row which works perfectly and I am able to delete the values I want but when I can't seem to get the table reload working. Even after deleting the row data, the table doesn't update itself. I am calling reloadData after successful deletion. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did this error occur when you pressed didPressButton?
Are you sure you removed the object you deleted from the scheduleArray and then reload it?

Comment: Yes, when I press the 'delete' button in the custom cell 'scheduleCell and didPressButton is called. I am deleting the value here (after delete UIAlert): 

self.scheduler![self.day]?.remove(at: tag)
self.scheduleView.reloadData()

Comment: The line `....self.scheduleArray?[indexPath.row][0]....` assumes that collection contains at least 2 items. That´s the problem here. How do you assure that is true?

Comment: It is indexPath.row which is causing the crash. I am printing the indexPath values to console in the same function and it is not getting updated. For example, the array contained 4 arrays of 2 values each (startTime and endTime), now I deleted one pair of values (i.e. one row deleted), still the indexPath.row goes unto 4, whereas it should be going only up till 3.

Comment: The next lead would be that your are changing the collection during `cellForItemAt`with this line: `scheduleArray = scheduler![self.day]`. This seems sketchy at best and just wrong in general. But posting a [mre] would allow us to debug this code and see for ourselves instead of just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you are holding multiple sources of truth and fail at synchronysing them. You have:

```
var scheduleArray : Array<Array<String>>?
var scheduler : [String : Array<Array<String>>]?
```

Where both seem to hold the same information in different form. I can´t see why you are doing this from the example code you posted.

You get an error at:

```
self.scheduleArray?[indexPath.row][0]
```

because when you delete your item you are removing it from `scheduler` and reload your tableview. The tableview on the other hand get´s the information how many rows it should render from `scheduleArray`:

```
return scheduleArray?.count ?? 0
```

and these differ at that time because you didn´t assign `scheduler` to `scheduleArray`.

So 2 possible solutions here:

- assign `scheduleArray` before you reload your tableview

  ```
  self.scheduler![self.day]?.remove(at: tag)
  scheduleArray = scheduler![self.day]
  ```

and remove the assignment in the `cellForItemAt` function

- stop using `scheduleArray` and `scheduler`. Use only a single collection to hold the information.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly the problem. For now, I have solved it by using self.showDetail function, instead of self.tableView.reload. But I trust your solution would work 100%. Silly mistake on my part for using two arrays to hold the same information, was doing it for convenience sake. But works for now.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 issues

- when you update something on UI after a request call, you have to push the UI update process back to the main thread (tableview.reloadData() should get triggered on the main thread)
- self.scheduleArray?[indexPath.row][0] and self.scheduleArray?[indexPath.row][1] is the issue index out of range. Because you assume it always contains 2 items without safe check.

I've  refactored the code a bit as below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduleCell") else {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("scheduleCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! scheduleCell
    }
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    cell.editBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteSchedule.tag = indexPath.row
    scheduleArray = scheduler?[self.day]
   
    guard let item = scheduleArray?[indexPath.row], item.count == 2 else {
        return cell
    }
    if let firstLabel = item.first, let secondLabel = item.last {
        cell.timeLabel1.text = firstLabel
        cell.timeLabel2.text = secondLabel
    }
    return cell
}

func didPressButton(_ tag: Int, btnType: String) {
    let deleteURL = K.delURL
    if(btnType == "delete") {
        AFFunctions.deleteAFRequest(ofType: scheduleResponse.self, url: "\(deleteURL)?day=\(self.day)&place=\(tag)") { [self]
            responseData, statusCode in
            if(statusCode == 200){
                // This has to be executed on the main thread to get tableView updated
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let deleteAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Deleted", message: "Device Schedule Successfully Deleted", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                    
                    deleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                        self.scheduler![self.day]?.remove(at: tag)
                        self.scheduleView.reloadData()
                        
                    }))
                    self.present(deleteAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regards to second point, the data is always in pair of 2. It is an array of array of Strings Like this : [["0635", "0740"], ["0835", "0940"], ["1035", "1140"]]

So it is never the case that in the sub-array, only 1 value is there. There will always be 2 values. The issue is when the Indexpath.row is out of range. So as you see above, there are 3 entries. When I delete one of them, the indexpath does not get updated and hence, the out of range error.

I tried the code above, and unfortunately, the same error still comes.

Comment: Since you access and delete an array at the same time. The second answer mentioned it. Also it will be helpful when you give enough context then people can give you right answers

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Updated Code :

```
class SchedulerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
scheduleCellDelegate
{

    
    var scheduleArray : Array<Array<String>>?
    var scheduler : [String : Array<Array<String>>]?
    var deviceID : String = ""
    let retrievedString = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token")

    var day = ""
    var dayNum = 0
  
    @IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var scheduleView: UITableView!
    
    var header : HTTPHeaders? = nil
    var ScheduleURL : Dictionary<String, String>?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scheduleView.delegate = self
        scheduleView.dataSource = self
        spinner.isHidden = true
        //scheduleView.allowsSelection = false
        scheduleView.register(UINib(nibName: "schedulerCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "schedulerCell")
        self.getData()
        
        
    }
    
    func getData(){
       
      
        self.header =
        [
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
            "Authorization": retrievedString!
        ]
        //scheduleView.register(scheduleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "scheduleCell")
       
        print(ScheduleURL!["GET"])
        AFFunctions.getAFRequest(ofType: ScheduleResponse.self, url: ScheduleURL!["GET"]!) { responseData, statusCode in
            print(responseData?.data?.scheduler, statusCode)
            self.scheduler = responseData?.data?.scheduler
            self.scheduleView.reloadData()

        }
    }
    
   
    var buttonNum : Int?
    
    @IBAction func daySelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        self.buttons.forEach { $0.tintColor = ($0 == sender) ? UIColor.orange : UIColor.systemTeal }
        
        self.dayNum = sender.tag
        print(sender.tag)
        switch dayNum {
        case 0 : self.day = "Sunday"
        case 1 : self.day = "Monday"
        case 2 : self.day = "Tuesday"
        case 3 : self.day = "Wednesday"
        case 4 : self.day = "Thursday"
        case 5 : self.day = "Friday"
        case 6 : self.day = "Saturday"
        default : self.day = "Sunday"
        }
        print(day, dayNum)
        showDetail(day : day)
    }
    
    
    
    
    func showDetail(day : String) {
        
        print(day)
        print(scheduler?[day])
        if let dayArray = scheduler?[day]
        {   print(dayArray)
            scheduleArray = dayArray
            self.scheduleView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("111 CHECK")
        return scheduleArray?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("scheduleCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! scheduleCell
        cell.cellDelegate = self
        cell.editBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.deleteSchedule.tag = indexPath.row
        if let item = scheduleArray?[indexPath.row],
           item.count > 1 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.timeLabel1.text = item[0]
                cell.timeLabel2.text = item[1]
            }
               }

        return cell
    }
    

  
    
    func didPressButton(_ tag: Int, btnType: String) {
        let deleteURL = K.delURL
        print("134", self.day)
        print("135", self.scheduleArray?[tag])
        print("136", scheduler?[self.day])
        print("TAG : ", tag)
        print("BTN TYPE: ", btnType)
        if(btnType == "delete") {
            AFFunctions.deleteAFRequest(ofType: scheduleResponse.self, url: "\(deleteURL)?day=\(self.day)&place=\(tag)") { [self]
                responseData, statusCode in
                print("\(deleteURL)?day=\(self.day)&place=\(tag)")
                print(responseData, statusCode)
                if(statusCode == 200){
                    self.scheduler![self.day]!.remove(at: tag)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let deleteAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Deleted", message: "Device Schedule Successfully Deleted", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                    deleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                        self.showDetail(day: self.day)
//                        self.scheduleView.reloadData()
                        
                     }))
                    self.present(deleteAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
}
```